# To send email through mvc3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, smtp

I'm using MVC3 and need to send an email to a user. I don't want to use a gmail server.  But, I do want to use server 10.1.70.100.  I don't understand what I am doing wrong.  Here is my code:

```
                var fromAddress = new MailAddress("sum1@abc.com", "From Name");                    var toAddress = new MailAddress(EmailID, "To Name");
                const string fromPassword = "";//To be Filled
                const string subject = "Verification Mail";

                string body = "You have successfully registered yourself. Please Enter your Verification code " + code.ActivatedCode;
                var smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "10.1.70.100",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(),

                    Timeout = 100000
                };
                using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
                {
                    Subject = subject,
                    Body = body
                })
                {
                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
```

**Can someone suggest a way through which I don't have to give my credentials??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For our OSS project we use this little helper. Hope it helps.

```
public void SendEmail(string address, string subject, string message)
    {
        string email = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("email");
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("password");
        string client = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("client");
        string port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("port");

        NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential(email, password);
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(client, int.Parse(port));

        msg.From = new MailAddress(email);
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(address));
        msg.Subject = subject;
        msg.Body = message;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = loginInfo;
        smtpClient.Send(msg);
    }
```

Comment: Zuri :Thanx for replying bt can u suggest me sumthing through which i dont have to give my Credentials??

Comment: Use a service account, we have a domain service account which all email is sent thru such as noreply@domain

Comment: using credentials depend on mail server configuration. Services like gmail enforce using ssl and credentials for sending email acc. Some hosting providers provide pop access without ssl and credentials but you have to ask their customer support. I agree with @CDSmith and suggest you create service email that your app will use, and it will greatly improve your security. If noreply is not an options create mail address that you will forward to your own mail and continue communication with customers with personal email that is secured.

Comment: @GoranŽuri : THnx for helping me

Answer (score 2):

I prefer doing this on the following way:

Web.config:

```
   <system.net>
       <mailSettings>
           <smtp from="Description">
               <network host="your.smtpserver" password="" userName="" />
           </smtp>
      </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Your code:

```
      var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
      smtpClient.Send(mail);
```